# How to provide two input lines to command executed with Plink

Tags: ssh, unix, shell, putty, plink

I have a issue like my script prompts to type `Yes` or `No` after `sudo` password prompt. So my question is if we have some way to pass two `echo` back to back? How can I do it?

```
plink -ssh -no-antispoof USERNAME@SERVERNAME -pw PASSWORD -t "echo PASSWORD | sudo -S /path/to/shellscript/test.sh;"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options. You can for example use a compound statement:

```
"(echo PASSWORD ; echo yes) | sudo -S /path/to/shellscript/test.sh;"
```

---

*Though even better would be to modify your script to allow automatic processing (e.g. by specifying the desired option using a command-line argument).*

*Similarly automating `sudo` is not the right way to go. Allowing your script to be automatically executed with a specific key pair is a better option.*

Comment: thanks for suggestion and current provided solution also work for me... You are great...